# SwipeRefreshView with tabview conflict and fragments not refreshing

Tags: android

I am trying to add a refreshing view on my APP. problem is whenever I try to switch between my tabs. SwipeRefresh activates. I tried moving it on several parts of the code but I still get this. I tried Moving SwipeRefreshlayout onto one of my fragments and it crashes with the null pointer.  and to top it all up even if I refresh the fragment does not recognize it.

My latest try is making the entire containt_main.xml as my swiperefresh. and again it activates when trying to move between tabs

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/refresh">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:elevation="4dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">



                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            </RelativeLayout>

         <FrameLayout
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
          />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**my fragment XML.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardview">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

this code block is in my mainactivity Reader.class reads XML xml and saves it on the database.

```
  final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,R.color.colorPrimaryDark,R.color.colorAccent);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Reader fromthepast = new Reader(getApplicationContext(), "RSSLINK (censored)", "fromthepast");


                        fromthepast.execute();


                    }
                },3000);
            }
        });

    }
```

and I have my refreshlistener on the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .detach(this)
            .attach(this)
            .commit();

}
```

Error Log

```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.lemesosblog.lemesosblog, PID: 27482
>     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(int[])'
> on a null object reference
>         at com.lemesosblog.lemesosblog.Fragment.fromthepast_Fragment.onCreateView(fromthepast_Fragment.java:46)
>         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
>         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
>         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
>         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
>         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:663)
>         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:625)
>         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:606)
>         at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2170)
>         at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1165)
>         at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1158)
>         at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1128)
>         at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1427)
>         at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1537)
>         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24828)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
> D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `SwipeRefreshLayout` as parent

You must add `SwipeRefreshLayout` for each `RecyclerView`

*fragment.xml*

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/refresh1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Hello by doing that I get Nullpointer exception. 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(int[])' on a null object reference
        at com.lemesosblog.lemesosblog.Fragment.fromthepast_Fragment.onCreateView(fromthepast_Fragment.java:44)

Line 44:    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.refresh);
     swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary,R.color.colorPrimaryDark,R.color.colorAccent);

Comment: @Demeteor you forget initilize swipeRefreshLayout in fragment . i have refresh1 id in my code

Comment: changed it my self without the use of 1. before replying. still the error exist
Had tried this also prior to posting.

Comment: @Demeteor edit your code with new code plus error log please

Comment: Added the error log. let me know if you need anything extra. personally I am stuck on this for a few days. going back and forth on to where I am going wrong.
This null pointer was the reason why I moved it on containt_main.xml

Comment: and share fromthepast_Fragment xml file

Comment: its the one with the recyclerview.

Comment: @Demeteor yes i want that

Comment: I am sorry I did not explain that well. the layout you are looking for is the one who you used to try and solve my problem.  (the one in your answer) 
Sorry for not being clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185420/discussion-between-radesh-and-demeteor).

Comment: Hey, 
I dont know if you get a notification if I reply on the post so I am replying here..
I posted the code you asked for in the chat

Comment: ok I finally figure it out after re-reading the code a million times. in my fragment I had 
  final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout =  
 getActivity.findViewById(R.id.refresh1);  where ofc it would not work since I am using a fragment and also have oncreateview. changed it to view.findviewbyid and worked.  (view is my layout inflate)


Edit: If you can edit your answer and also add it it would be great.

Comment: i'm so glad. that why i want see your fragment code. this NPE crash can make  with so many ways not only this one. happy coding...